# `Internal Server Error` when New-AzWebApp cmdlet handling `-SourceWebApp` parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm running into an issue when executing a Powershell 7 script to migrate Azure WebApps from one subscription to another that was designed and proven to function about one month ago (end of July).
The issue comes in the midst of this code block:

```
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionID $MPNSubscription
    $srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webApp.WebAppName
    #move into prod sub
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $ProdSubscription
    $DestWebApp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $DestRGName -Name $DestWebAppName -Location $DestLocation -AppServicePlan $DestASPName -SourceWebApp $srcapp
```

Without getting into attempted troubleshooting at this point, The issue occurs in the execution of this final line. The resultant error is below:

```
Line |
 286 |  … estWebApp = New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $DestRGName -Name $DestWe …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Long running operation failed with status 'InternalServerError'.
```

When the `-SourceWebApp` parameter is removed, the `New-AzWebApp` process succeeds (creates resource). The issue being, of course, that now this is a blank WebApp rather than a clone from my dev subscription.

Expected results:
The successfully cloned WebApp should be a copy of all directories deployed to $srcapp on $MPNSubcription, with $DestWebApp itself deployed to $ProdSubscription
Actual Results:
No resources created, error above.
Troubleshooting:

Double-checked and updated Powershell 7 modules with the following commands-

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
import-module Az
Install-Module AzTable
Import-Module AzTable
Install-Module az.websites
Import-Module az.websites
```

Logged out of Azure and logged back in-

```
logout-azaccount
login-azaccount
```

Confirmed that variables are correctly populated
Confirmed target RG, ASP exist
Confirmed RBAC for target resources
**REMOVED PARAMETER `-SourceWebApp`** - This created the expected WebApp, but does not meet requirements, as it is not a copy of $srcapp .

I'm wondering if this parameter has changed its behavior?
I designed this code according to the Microsoft recommendation, though it admittedly doesn't mention moving between subs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning
This is so puzzling to me, as the original code functioned so recently, yet module updates did not resolve the problem.